# How to bypass login screen on boot?

Tags: startup, auto-login

I installed Ubuntu to dual boot on my XP box but it wouldn't ever work, so I uninstalled it and am now downloading it to install as a stand-alone OS on another PC.

But one thing it did do that drove me insane was that it kept asking me to enter a username & password *every time* I (tried to) log on.

So after I get it installed and up & running (I hope) is there some way to make it just go on when I push the ON button without having it ask for a username & password, like XP does?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Go to **System Settings > User Accounts** and turn on **automatic login**. That’s it.

[image]

Note that you should *unlock* on the right top corner before you could change user accounts.

Comment: I changed it in Ubuntu 17.10, but it resets back to OFF after a reboot.